# People Picker is not taking more than 256 Characters

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, limitations, boundaries

I do have an InfoPath form in which I want to add a people Picker Field to validate a bulk of users that is normally more than 256 char , but I always get this alerting message (Item cannot be more than 256 characters)

I am looking for a solution avoiding any coding , however I tried a work around to feed the people picker by a multi line text field that accepts more than 256 char but it didn't help in the validation option.

Answer (score 0):

These are built-in limits for list columns, both in SharePoint sites and on list forms, **255** characters for Person or group column and **63999** characters for Multiple line of Text Column.

There is no way around it if you are accepting OOB solutions only.